# Typescript Definition File Creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, definitions

I am attempting to write a typescript definition file for a js library.
The library exports the following item:

```
const Joi = require('joi');
module.exports = {
  Joi
};
```

Joi is a popular library and already has types defined. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/joi)

How can I properly export the preexistent Joi types in my definition file without redefining a namespace within my definition file?
What is the proper way to do this?

I have used the tool dts-gen (https://github.com/Microsoft/dts-gen) to get an idea.  It creates a namespace for Joi as follows:

```
export namespace Joi {

    const isImmutable: boolean;

    const isJoi: boolean;

    const schemaType: string;

    const version: string;

    function allow(...args: any[]): void;

    function alt(args: any): any;

    function alternatives(args: any): any;

    function any(args: any): any;

    function applyFunctionToChildren(...args: any[]): void;

    function array(args: any): any;

    function assert(value: any, schema: any, message: any): void;

    function attempt(value: any, schema: any, message: any): any;

    function binary(args: any): any;

    function bool(args: any): any;

    function checkOptions(...args: any[]): void;

    function clone(...args: any[]): void;

    function compile(schema: any): any;

    function concat(...args: any[]): void;

    function createError(...args: any[]): void;

    function createOverrideError(...args: any[]): void;

    function date(args: any): any;

    function defaults(fn: any): any;

    function describe(args: any): any;

    function description(...args: any[]): void;

    function disallow(...args: any[]): void;

    function empty(...args: any[]): void;

    function equal(...args: any[]): void;

    function error(...args: any[]): void;

    function example(...args: any[]): void;

    function exist(...args: any[]): void;

    function extend(args: any): any;

    function forbidden(...args: any[]): void;

    function func(args: any): any;

    function invalid(...args: any[]): void;

    function isRef(ref: any): any;

    function label(...args: any[]): void;

    function lazy(fn: any): any;

    function meta(...args: any[]): void;

    function not(...args: any[]): void;

    function notes(...args: any[]): void;

    function number(args: any): any;

    function object(args: any): any;

    function only(...args: any[]): void;

    function optional(...args: any[]): void;

    function options(...args: any[]): void;

    function raw(...args: any[]): void;

    function reach(schema: any, path: any): any;

    function ref(args: any): any;

    function required(...args: any[]): void;

    function strict(...args: any[]): void;

    function string(args: any): any;

    function strip(...args: any[]): void;

    function tags(...args: any[]): void;

    function unit(...args: any[]): void;

    function valid(...args: any[]): void;

    function validate(value: any, args: any): any;

    function when(...args: any[]): void;

    namespace alt {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace alternatives {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace any {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace array {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace assert {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace attempt {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace binary {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace bool {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace compile {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace date {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace defaults {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace describe {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace extend {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace extensionSchema {
        const isImmutable: boolean;

        const isJoi: boolean;

        const schemaType: string;

        function allow(...args: any[]): void;

        function and(...args: any[]): void;

        function applyFunctionToChildren(...args: any[]): void;

        function assert(...args: any[]): void;

        function checkOptions(...args: any[]): void;

        function clone(...args: any[]): void;

        function concat(...args: any[]): void;

        function createError(...args: any[]): void;

        function createOverrideError(...args: any[]): void;

        function describe(...args: any[]): void;

        function description(...args: any[]): void;

        function disallow(...args: any[]): void;

        function empty(...args: any[]): void;

        function equal(...args: any[]): void;

        function error(...args: any[]): void;

        function example(...args: any[]): void;

        function exist(...args: any[]): void;

        function forbidden(...args: any[]): void;

        function forbiddenKeys(...args: any[]): void;

        function invalid(...args: any[]): void;

        function keys(...args: any[]): void;

        function label(...args: any[]): void;

        function length(...args: any[]): void;

        function max(...args: any[]): void;

        function meta(...args: any[]): void;

        function min(...args: any[]): void;

        function nand(...args: any[]): void;

        function not(...args: any[]): void;

        function notes(...args: any[]): void;

        function only(...args: any[]): void;

        function optional(...args: any[]): void;

        function optionalKeys(...args: any[]): void;

        function options(...args: any[]): void;

        function or(...args: any[]): void;

        function pattern(...args: any[]): void;

        function raw(...args: any[]): void;

        function rename(...args: any[]): void;

        function required(...args: any[]): void;

        function requiredKeys(...args: any[]): void;

        function schema(...args: any[]): void;

        function strict(...args: any[]): void;

        function strip(...args: any[]): void;

        function tags(...args: any[]): void;

        function type(...args: any[]): void;

        function unit(...args: any[]): void;

        function unknown(...args: any[]): void;

        function valid(...args: any[]): void;

        function validate(...args: any[]): void;

        function when(...args: any[]): void;

        function without(...args: any[]): void;

        function xor(...args: any[]): void;

    }

    namespace extensionsSchema {
        const isImmutable: boolean;

        const isJoi: boolean;

        const schemaType: string;

        function allow(...args: any[]): void;

        function applyFunctionToChildren(...args: any[]): void;

        function checkOptions(...args: any[]): void;

        function clone(...args: any[]): void;

        function concat(...args: any[]): void;

        function createError(...args: any[]): void;

        function createOverrideError(...args: any[]): void;

        function describe(...args: any[]): void;

        function description(...args: any[]): void;

        function disallow(...args: any[]): void;

        function empty(...args: any[]): void;

        function equal(...args: any[]): void;

        function error(...args: any[]): void;

        function example(...args: any[]): void;

        function exist(...args: any[]): void;

        function forbidden(...args: any[]): void;

        function invalid(...args: any[]): void;

        function items(...args: any[]): void;

        function label(...args: any[]): void;

        function length(...args: any[]): void;

        function max(...args: any[]): void;

        function meta(...args: any[]): void;

        function min(...args: any[]): void;

        function not(...args: any[]): void;

        function notes(...args: any[]): void;

        function only(...args: any[]): void;

        function optional(...args: any[]): void;

        function options(...args: any[]): void;

        function ordered(...args: any[]): void;

        function raw(...args: any[]): void;

        function required(...args: any[]): void;

        function single(...args: any[]): void;

        function sparse(...args: any[]): void;

        function strict(...args: any[]): void;

        function strip(...args: any[]): void;

        function tags(...args: any[]): void;

        function unique(...args: any[]): void;

        function unit(...args: any[]): void;

        function valid(...args: any[]): void;

        function validate(...args: any[]): void;

        function when(...args: any[]): void;

    }

    namespace func {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace isRef {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace lazy {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace number {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace object {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace reach {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace ref {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace string {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

    namespace validate {
        const prototype: {
        };

    }

}
```

This however does not seem right to me.  I don't understand the need for a namespace for Joi when the actual definitions already exist.

Thanks

Comment: What is your problem? If existing definitions exists, what you do you want to add? And why you can not do this?